# AppendCellsRequest Google sheets api c#

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I am trying to append a row of cells in a spreadsheet using c# and the google sheets api. I got the code

```
    AppendCellsRequest appReq = new AppendCellsRequest();
    appReq.SheetId = 1;
```

The problem is that the only sheetID I got is from the url and is a String. Where do I find the sheet ID as an integer and how do I execute the AppendCellsRequest?

Hopes you can help.

Answer (score 1):

You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest) and this [example](https://github.com/Alex-Malik/Time-Sheet-Helper/blob/0366e53cc3c986d3eb684a3fbe73a6edbddcd1c2/TimeSheet/Services/Google/GoogleService.cs). The `fields` of CellData should be updated. At least one field must be specified. The root is the `CellData`; `'row.values.'` should not be specified. A single `*` can be used as short-hand for listing every field.

```
// Create 'append cells' request for the current sheet.
   AppendCellsRequest appendRequest = new AppendCellsRequest();
   appendRequest.SheetId = 0;
   appendRequest.Rows = new[] { newRow };
   appendRequest.Fields = "*";
```

Here are some references which might help:

- [Google Sheets API v4 C# update a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462887/google-sheets-api-v4-c-sharp-update-a-cell)
- [Adding a row to a google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518694/adding-a-row-to-a-google-spreadsheet)

You may also check this [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.cs) for the sample code.

Comment: Can you please explain what is this "Fields" actually used for, What other values besides `*` can be given for this?

Comment: Sorry for the noise, got answers to my doubt. Just in case if anybody else has a hard time figuring out: Fields are supposed to update thing from the set of values.eg: `fields: 'userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.textFormat.bold'`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're confusing "spreadsheetId" and "sheetId".  The spreadsheet ID is the ID of the entire spreadsheet -- it's in the URL and is a long alphanumeric string (sometimes with dashes, underscores or some other characters).  The "sheet ID" is the ID of a specific tab within the spreadsheet and is numeric.

Sheet IDs are visible in the URL after the "gid=" parameter, and are also available in the API from the spreadsheets.get call, under sheets.properties.sheetId.